# How can I use pyserial write() with python 3.8?

Tags: python, pyserial

Using Python 3.8 and pySerial for serial communications.
I think "ser.write(b'\x01D1\x0D\x04')" is going something wrong, but I don't know what to do.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM1',\
    baudrate=9600,\
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=0)


ser.write(b'\x01D1\x0D\x04')
#####ser.write(b'\x01'+'D'+'1'+b'\x0D\x04')
```

Comment: Looks ok. What makes you think it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, python38 now requires the data to be sent needs to be encoded...
I ran into this problem, on python27 I could send any byte, but now you are limited to a 7-bit value (encode('utf-8')...